# Docker container cannot resolve dns

Tags: dns

I'm trying to configure my docker container to see my local private rpm repository through http.  It cannot resolve the dns name and I'm probably not setting up DNS correctly on the host CENTOS 6.5 VM.

> http://
>   172.17.42.1

/repository/CENTOS/6/nginx/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml:

> [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - > "couldn't connect to host"
>
> bash-4.1# more /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
>
> > [nginx]
> >     name=nginx repo
> >
> > > baseurl=http://
> > >       172.17.42.1/repository/CENTOS/$releasever/nginx/$basearch/
>
> (can't connect to host)
>
> > gpgcheck=0
> >     enabled=1
>
> **The container /etc/resolv.conf contains this**
>
> > bash-4.1# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
> >     nameserver 192.168.64.2
> >     nameserver 192.168.64.129
> >     nameserver 127.0.0.1
> >     search localdomain eadis.local
>
> When I try to add the domainname to the IP address it does not
>   resolve.
>
> **Docker container IP address**
>
> > eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7E:EB:4C:25:F4:DA
> >              inet addr:172.17.0.7  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
>
> **Host VM Docker server**
>
> > docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:EF:63:A8:65:5C
> >
> > inet addr:
> >     172.17.42.1

Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0

> > eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:10:0A:77
> >              inet addr:192.168.64.129  Bcast:192.168.64.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
> >
> > [root@centos named]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
> >
> > > > domain localdomain 
> > > >         search localdomain eadis.local 
> > > >         nameserver 192.168.64.129 
> > > >         nameserver 192.168.64.2

Answer (score 0):

When you run your container with `--net` or `--network`, docker will use a self DNS server to discover services that runs with it. All DNS queries are sent to the docker engine.

In normal times (when using default network) you can use the `--dns` option on your run command. But when you run your images with a self-defined network, you must add your customize `resolv.conf` file to the container. You make one on your system and name it `custom-resolv.conf`.

In this file you can add your custom dns address and add it to your container.

```
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

Then you must add this small part to your run command:

```
-v /path/to/file/custom-resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf:ro
```

Use `ro` for read-only volume mapping. When your container is started, you can exec to your container and check the `/etc/resolv.conf` file which must be the same as `custom-resolv.conf`.

Now all of your DNS requests are sent to your DNS server.

Comment: You have posted the same answer in [several other places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71101852/14267427). If you think this question is a duplicate, flag it as a duplicate or reference the other post in the comments instead of providing the same answers in multiple areas throughout the site.